# What is the acceleration due to gravity, air resistance and Archimedes' principle on a plane with initial velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, drag

So, I am having some fun with doing physics, and I was trying to find the acceleration of a plane moving vertically in mid-air with initial velocity under the influence of: gravity, air resistance, and Archimedes' force.

Per Newton's second law:
$$\sum \vec{F} = m\vec{a}.$$
Therefore
$$\vec{P} + \vec{A} + \vec{R} = m\vec{a},$$
where $\vec{P}$ is gravity, $\vec{A}$ Archimedes'force, and $\vec{R}$ air resistance.

Now Archimedes' force and air resistance are always against movement, so both forces will add up. Since the plane is moving in a straight line, gravity is perpendicular to $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{P}$; therefore we have to consider the sum as the hypotenuse of a right triangle.

And as per my education at school, we know that $A = \rho vg$,
where $\rho$ is the mass/volume ratio of air, which is 1.2 kg/m$^3$, I thin; $v$ is the total volume of the plane; and $g$ is the gravitational acceleration.

$R = kV^{2}$, where $k$ is the viscosity coefficient of air, and $V$ is the plane's speed.

Therefore:
$$(ma)^2 = (kV^2 + \rho vg)^2 + (mg)^2$$
$$(ma)^2 = (kV^{2})^2 + (\rho vg)^2 + 2kV^{2}gv \rho + (mg)^2$$
$$a^2 = \left(\frac{kV^2}{m}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\rho vg}{m}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{V\sqrt{2kgv \rho}}{m}\right)^2 + g^2$$
Therefore:
$$a = \sqrt{\left(\frac{kV^2}{m}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\rho vg}{m}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{V\sqrt{2kgv \rho}}{m}\right)^2 + g^2}$$

Now that's a kind of messy expression for the acceleration and I want a better one, a cleaner one.

Is there any way to make that equation much simpler?

Also please I know some people are advanced in here and my concepts of air resistance or Archimedes' force may be outdated to them, but I don't want to go through what I am not meant to learn yet.

So please when answering, keep it to my level.

Comment: The buoyant force is vertical no matter how it moves. And if it moves vertically, the air resistance is also vertical.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you could consider neglecting Archimedes' force. If you deal with a thin plane (like a piece of paper) its volume is relatively small e.g. in comparison with the air resistance. Moreover, if you consider only a short period of time you can even neglect gravitational force. Especially when the initial velocity is huge.

Comment: That's true. However, my formula is rather for big planes.

Comment: sure, remember that $k$ is proportional to the area of a plane, so everything I wrote should apply to your formula.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out in other answers, the buoyant force is always upwards, not in the direction of motion.  So it should be vertically and upwards, not horizontal.

Moreover, if air resistance, buoyancy, and gravity are the only forces acting on the object, then the object will not move horizontally for long.  Rather, the net force will have both vertical and horizontal coordinates, and so will the acceleration vector.  This means that the horizontal *and* vertical components of the velocity will be constantly changing, and even if the vertical component of the velocity is zero at one instant, the vertical component of the acceleration will cause the velocity to gain a vertical component quickly after that.